# tableview (list) and modal (add+edit) : how to proceed after validation on modal?

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is a software design question, how to proceed after validation on 2nd screen (red arrow) ? There are many ways to achieve this, just wondering which one is the best.

[image: views]

On screen 2, when the user clicks on save, we have mainly 4 things to do.

1. Copy the information to item

   > ```
   > item.attribute1 = UITextField1.text
   > item.attribute2 = UITextField2.text
   > ...
   > ```
2. Save item (we use an ORM similar to CoreData). Popup an alert on error

   > ```
   > BOOL error = [item save]
   > ...
   > ```
3. If success, update list (on screen 1)

   > ```
   > ...
   > [tableView reloadData]
   > ```
4. And remove the view (screen 2)

   > ```
   > [self dismiss...]
   > ```

The question is, which controller should be in charge of each step (1...4) and how should they communicate between each other with delegate + protocol?

1st solution : On screen 2 controller, do steps 1 and 2. If save succeed, call screen 1 controller delegate and do step 3. Then back to screen 2 controller, remove himself.

2nd solution : On screen 2 controller, just do step 1. Call screen 1 controller and do 2+3+4.

Maybe otherwise ?

Thanks!

Comment: as we know nothing about your orm (and core data is not an orm), we cant advice you, how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

from my opinion screen 2 should do 1, 2, 4 step and when screen 2 call dismiss view it should be

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:nil userInfo:userInfo]; }];
```

that make you to implement NSNotification with screen 1 before modal the screen 2 like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadDataWithNotification:) name:@"reloadData" object:nil]; 
}

- (void)reloadDataWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a bit overkill to me, as delegation would be just enough. or reload the data in `viewWillAppear:`